Is there a way to write json.gz data to S3 using PyFlink in Python?
I developed the code using PyFlink's Table API.
What is the method to write to S3 as JSON.gz using the Table API?
I’ve searched through the Flink documentation, but I couldn't find a method to write JSON data compressed as gzip, except for Parquet. If it’s not possible to write JSON.gz data to S3 using the Table API, is it possible with the DataStream API? Please help me.
from pyflink.table import EnvironmentSettings, StreamTableEnvironment


env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
env_settings = EnvironmentSettings.new_instance().in_streaming_mode().build()
table_env = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env, environment_settings=env_settings)



table_env.get_config().get_configuration().set_string("execution.checkpointing.interval", "60000")
table_env.get_config().get_configuration().set_string("execution.checkpointing.timeout", "600000")
table_env.get_config().get_configuration().set_string("execution.checkpointing.max-concurrent-checkpoints", "1")
table_env.get_config().get_configuration().set_string("execution.checkpointing.min-pause", "5000")
table_env.get_config().get_configuration().set_string("execution.checkpointing.mode", "EXACTLY_ONCE")


table_env.execute_sql("""
    CREATE TABLE source_table (
        col_1 VARCHAR(512),
        col_2 VARCHAR(512),
        col_3 VARCHAR(512) ...
    ) WITH (
        'connector' = 'kafka',
        'topic' = 'my_topic',
        'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'my.bootstrap.servers:9096',
        'properties.group.id' = 'my_group_id',
        'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
        'format' = 'json',
        'properties.security.protocol' = 'SASL_SSL',
        'properties.sasl.mechanism' = 'SCRAM-SHA-512',
        'properties.sasl.jaas.config' = 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="my-user" password="my-password";'
    )
""")


table_env.execute_sql("""
    CREATE TABLE sink_table (
        col_1 VARCHAR(512),
        col_2 VARCHAR(512),
        col_3 VARCHAR(512) ...
    ) PARTITIONED BY (origin, kst_time, `minute`)
    WITH (
        'connector' = 'filesystem',
        'path' = 's3://tving-de-kr-dev-raw/watchlog/watchlog_origin_v1_flink_json/',
        'format' = 'json',
        'sink.rolling-policy.file-size' = '32MB',
        'sink.rolling-policy.rollover-interval' = '1 min',
        'sink.rolling-policy.check-interval' = '1 min'
    )
""")

table_env.execute_sql("""
    INSERT INTO sink_table
    SELECT *
    FROM source_table
""")

